# display image from array in android

Tags: java, android

I declared the following array which contains images:

```
private int[] LEAVES = { 
            R.drawable.leaf_green, 
            R.drawable.leaf_red,
            R.drawable.leaf_yellow,
            R.drawable.leaf_other,
        };
```

If I would want to show one image from the array how can I refer to a specific image? let's say I would want to refer to LEAVES[1]. How can I display it?

Comment: At least asked question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually setImageResource method  sets a drawable as the content of  ImageView. It takes id of drawable as argument. Here we have array of drawable ids. we can pick drawable id from array to use. below code shows syntax of of the method.

```
imageView.setImageResource(LEAVES[1]);
```